# Jenkins - One job for all branches or One job per branch?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

What is the best practice to automate build with Jenkins? I could have one Jenkins job and use the `$GIT_BRANCH` variable to make some decision on workflow. Or I could have one Jenkins job per branch (eg. one Jenkins job for master branch and another for develop branch).

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 3):

It depends. Choose the variable method if:

- The difference in behavior is minimal
- There are a lot of branches
- There are downstream jobs which also depend on the branch variable

Choose the one per job method if any of those previous reasons are false, or you need to deploy differently on each branch, simultaneously (like all branches have code changes at the same time).

In general, I would recommend using the environment variable and making a parametrized job. If you still want to make multiple jobs, I recommend using matrix jobs to track the many different dimensions you may build on.

Comment: If I go with one job for all branches I could not use the post action of Jenkins. I would like to choose the post action to use depends on the branch.

Comment: In those cases, I would either add the post-actions as part of the current job (as a separate task) and use switching logic to decide which post-action to do, or if that's not possible I would create a branch job. I've never used the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) but it might be right up your alley.